# In Twilio, what is the difference between Twilio number and logged in agent number?

Tags: twilio-click-to-call

In Twilio, what is the difference between Twilio number (For Customer Number) and logged in agent number?
Is every agent have unique Twilio number to receive an incoming call?

Answer (score 0):

I assume agent number you are referring to is a Twilio Client name.
Twilio Number is the number you bought from Twilio which can be used in the following cases .
  1.You can configure any call to this number. i.e., If the number receives any call, you can redirect to another number or say a common message or configure a ivr menu etc.,
  2.To initiate a outbound call from Twilio, you can set this number as the caller id.
Twilio Client on the other hand, is used to connect our web application client(Browser) side to Twilio and vice-versa.
The Client name is created while generating Capability token which is used for setting Twilio Device in our client side.Then ,the browser tab is identified as the Client name by the Twilio. (used while dialling your browser tab)

You can set a same client name for limited number of Twilio Devices.
For detailed information on Twilio Client, visit [this site.](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client)

Comment: Thanks Aatitya, actually I want to develop Power Dialer (Agent first), in which my application will fetch customer number and it will first connect to available agent/user and once agent accept the call then dial customer. Could you help me on this? I mean how to proceed with this solution?